# dev context in netlify.toml ignores environment variables

Tags: netlify

I'm trying to add environment variables per context using the `netlify.toml` file. I can add them through the netlify UI and they show up, but when I add them via the .toml file nothing appears under `process.env`.

This is how i'm doing it currently:

```
[dev]
   environment = { FOO = "BAR" }
```

Comment: Turns out Netlify doesn't support this currently: https://github.com/netlify/netlify-dev-plugin/issues/114

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether your context is correct, but here is the layout for context in the `netlify.toml`:

```
# Specific branch context: all deploys from this specific branch will inherit
# these settings.
[context.dev]
  environment = { FOO = "BAR" }
```

or this would work also

```
[context.dev.environment]
  FOO = "BAR"
```

Taken from the [docs](https://www.netlify.com/docs/netlify-toml-reference/)

Comment: I think it's correct according to https://github.com/netlify/netlify-dev-plugin#project-detection. They are using `[dev]` in their examples.

Comment: ok, they introduced `dev` block setting in `netlify dev`.  I see what you mean. Not sure they introduced environment variables locally yet from `netlify.toml`.